# C++, консольное приложение, защита от неправильного ввода

Tags: c++

В этом приложении входным данным должно быть натуральное число, при вводе целого или нуля и нажатия Enter программа начинается сначала и так пока не будет введено корректное значение. Тогда она вычисляет сумму факториалов натуральных чисел от 1 до введённого натурального числа. Но защита с помощью оператора else от неправильного ввода не работает против действительных чисел, дробное число воспринимается программой как 2 натуральных числа и программа после ввода дробного числа выполняется два раза подряд, первый раз для натурального числа идущего до точки и второй раз для натурального числа идущего после точки. Как защититься от ввода дробных чисел или чисел выходящих за диапазон типа переменной?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
long double factor (short x)
{
    long double k=1;
    short i;
    for (i=1; i<=x; i++) k=k*i;
    return k;
}
int main()
{
    long double s;
    short i, n;
    char ch;
    while ((ch=cin.get())='\n')
    {
        cout << "Vvedi naturalnoe chislo N<=1754: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n>0)
        {
            s=0;
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++) s=s+factor(i);
            if (n==1) cout << "S=1!=";
            else if (n==2) cout << "S=1!+2!=";
            else cout << "S=1!+...+" << n << "!=";
            cout.precision(16);
            cout << std::uppercase << s << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Считывай строку, а не число.

Comment: *"воспринимает число с десятичной точкой как два натуральных"* - [ничего подобного](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4OVuUCkGgnPRXdBC)

Comment: а если серьезно, то напишите хотябы неправильный код, чтоб можно было знать что у вас имеется и куда хотите вводить, и что вы сами пытались что то делать

Comment: Написал код своей программы

Comment: этот код работает?

Comment: Да, работает, но возможно ввести дробное число и тогда программа выполнится два раза подряд. Как исключить возможность пользователя задать дробное число?

Answer (score 1):

1. Считываете строку
2. Пробуете перевести ее в число
3. Смотрите на результат

```
string str;
cin >> str;
try {
  unsigned long num = stoul(str);
  if (num == 0)
    throw out_of_range("Number is zero");
  doProcess(num);
catch (exception e) {
  cout << e.what();
}
```

Comment: думаю автор вопроса не поймет код

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Тогда он сможет задать уточняющий вопрос

Comment: А за что минус?

Comment: а причем тут я ? Какой минус?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Это не Вам. Кто-то заминусовал ответ. Пытаюсь узнать за что?

Comment: это   точно  не  я, наверное кто то не понел

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняйте это значение в Int или long long, десятичная часть сама обрежется
Либо,

```
double a;
cin>>a;
int b = a;
if (abs(a-b) != 0)
    cout <<"введите натуральное число"<<endl;
```

Comment: abs(a-b)  == abs(0) и условие всегда будет false

Comment: @Senior Pomidor Вы про то, что abs нужно убрать или что?

Answer (score 0):

Раз вы написали свой, я напишу свой вариант

```
string s;
getline(cin, s);
transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
          [](char c) { if(!isdigit(c)) c = ' '; return c; });
istringstream is(s);
vector<int> integers;
int n = 0;
while(is >> n)
    integers.emplace_back(n); // в векторе хранятся ваши числа
```

может быть я не очень хорошо понел что вам нужно...